# How to Read SCF file in Python?

Tags: python, ngs, sequence-analysis, data-preprocessing

Is there any way that I can read [SCF](http://staden.sourceforge.net/manual/formats_unix_2.html) file in python like in R using [sangerseqR](https://rdrr.io/bioc/sangerseqR/man/read.scf.html), I have tried with [Biopython](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO), it seems it does not support this format.

Comment: You could try converting it to ABI format as asked in [this question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/692/how-can-i-convert-scf-trace-files-to-abi-files) and then import that

Comment: Alternatively, [bioconvert](https://bioconvert.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref_converters.html) supports conversion of SCF to FASTA and FASTQ formats.

Comment: Conversion to SCF to FASTA and FASTQ formats will not help me since I need the chromatography data not just the seq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was done using [sangerseqR](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/sangerseqR.html) with [rpy2](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/overview.html#) in python

```
    import rpy2.robjects as r
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
    utils = importr('utils')
    utils.install_packages('sangerseqR', repos="https://git.bioconductor.org/packages/sangerseqR")
    utils.chooseBioCmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list
    utils.install_packages('sangerseqR')


    sangerseqR = importr('sangerseqR')
    Trace = sangerseqR.readsangerseq( file="1I1_F_P1815443_047.scf") #scf sequence file is now loaded
```

[sangerseqR Documentation](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/sangerseqR/inst/doc/sangerseq_walkthrough.pdf)(pdf)